# strncmp in two statements takes more time than in single statement

Tags: c, linux, strncmp

For doing a file sorting in my code i used `strncmp` for the comparison of first elements of each string.

Including my code here :

**Code 1:**

```
for (i = 1; i < file_cnt; )
{
  if ((strncmp(info[i-1].name, "1", 1) == 0) && 
      (strncmp(info[i].name, "2", 1) == 0))
  {
    to do....
    i += 2;
  }
  else if ((strncmp(info[i-1].name, "2", 1) == 0) &&
           (strncmp(info[i].name, "1", 1) == 0))
  {
    to do....
    i += 2;
  }
  ...
}
```

**Code 2:**

```
for (i = 1; i < file_cnt; )
{
  if (strncmp(info[i-1].name, "1", 1) == 0)
  {
    if (strncmp(info[i].name, "2", 1) == 0)
    {
      to do....
      i += 2;
    }
  }
  else if (strncmp(info[i-1].name, "2", 1) == 0)
  {
    if (strncmp(info[i].name, "1", 1) == 0)
    {
      to do....
      i += 2;
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Here the `Code 2` takes comparatively more time than `Code 1`. I am working with a cross platform device and running `Code 2` on it causes many issues with other portions of my code.

Why is it that the two statement comparison taking more time than a single statement comparison?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Do you have optimization turned all the way up?  Also, why use `strncmp()` to compare only one character?  You could just compare the `char`s directly.

Comment: You can probably make it even "faster" if you *don't* use `strncmp`. Since you're only comparing two characters (don't forget the string terminator), you could do e,g, `if (info[i - 1].name[0] == '2' && info[i - 1].name[1] == '\0') ...`

Comment: Also note that the two code snippets are *not* equivalent. In the first code snippet, if the second `strncmp` in the first `if` is false, the code goes to the `else` which if both comparisons are true you do the code in it (e.g. `i += 2`. However in the second code snippet, if the first outer `if` is true, and the first nested `if` condition is false, you will ***not*** go to the `else`.

Comment: Thanks  Joachim Pileborg . For comparison of single character i could use the index. But in some other comparisons i want to compare more than one characters. There i have to use strncmp.

Comment: Oh, my first comment is kind of wrong, that check is equivalent to a `strcmp` call, not `strncmp`. If you're only comparing the first character then you don't need the extra check for the string terminator.

Comment: One more thing: Caching the results. Likely, in the previous iteration you've already compared `info[i].name` to `"1"` with i=1, now at i=2, you're comparing `info[i-1].name` to `"1"` repeating the previous operation. Remember results in some variables and reuse them.

Comment: All the strings are stored in the array "info" so is available every time. Also the value of i is incremented by 2 so that a single string is not compared twice.

Answer (score 1):

In code 1, you're using `&&` operator. The speciality is that it doesn't evaluate the second expression if the first expression(LHS) turns out to be false. This is called short-circuit evaluation. So if your first expression in code 1 is false, it directly goes to `else`.

Also, your nested if-statement will generate extra stack frame which will slow down the program(code 2)

Comment: Theoretically not different from the second code snippet, where if the expression in the outer `if` is false then the second (nested) comparison will not occur and the code will go straight to the `else`.

Comment: The same applies to code 2 also right? ie, if the first 'if' statement is false then it wont evaluate the second 'if ' statement inside it and moves to the else condition.

Comment: While I've known of the short-circuit evaluation for years, it still sometimes bites me in the rump if I forget to think about it. Just recently, an operation is retried a fixed number of times and at the end the number of tries is logged; the retry loop was like `do { ... } while (! operation_successful && (++tries_count) < tries_limit)`. If the operation is successful in the first try, tries_count shows 0. Switching the conditions around `&&` fixed the count.